# CS50 Week 6 Python Readability

Tags: python, for-loop

The problem set number 6 in cs50 requires to rebuild the Readability project from week 2 in Python
But there is a problem I haven't encountered first when writing the code in C
The programm uses for loop for each letter in input to check if its a period, exclamation point, or question mark which all indicate the end of a sentence
But the input that check50 throws at the program has multiple periods back to back each of which count as its own sentence
So the question is:
 **How can I improve this sentence counting function to only concider one of periods in case it encounters them back to back? Should I for example add a condition that sees next symbol in a for loop and if its also a period it just ignores it?**

```
def countSentences(input):
    counterS = 0
    for symbol in input:
        if symbol in ['.', '!', '?']:
            counterS += 1
    return counterS
```

Comment: "Should I for example add a condition that sees next symbol in a for loop and if its also a period it just ignores it?" - yes, this seems like a valid approach.

Comment: If this function was written by your lecturer then he commited the biggest sin of all, naming a variable to an inbuilt python function.

Comment: @TomMcLean while I myself would never do that for various reasons, in this case, considering that the name is local to that function, it's not exactly the worst case, mostly because it wouldn't affect `input` anywhere else (what I don't like more is not following PEP8)

Comment: @Matiiss Fair enough, not the worst case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the previous symbol in another variable. Then if it's the same as the current symbol, don't count it.

```
def countSentences(input):
    counterS = 0
    previous_symbol = None
    for symbol in input:
        if symbol in ['.', '!', '?']:
            if previous_symbol != symbol:
                counterS += 1
        previous_symbol = symbol
    return counterS
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about counting the sentences and not tracking which punctuation was used, you can use `re.sub` to squash duplicate punctuation into a single period (`.`). The function would look like the following

[Documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

```py
import re

def countSentences(input):
  counterS = 0
  for symbol in re.sub('[.!?]+', '.', input):
    if symbol in ['.', '!', '?']:
      counterS += 1
  return counterS
```